# Replacing asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete with ayncio.run

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.10

I'm trying to run [these asyncronyous tests](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/test/test_async.py), I run them by running this from the command line while in the root of this library `node run-tests gateio --python-async`

This code below causes a deprecation warning because I am using something ([tox](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox)) that depends on `python3.10` and it looks like `get_event_loop` is deprecated with `python3.10`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**Deprecation Warning**

```js
[100%] Testing gateio WARN (testExchange @ run-tests.js:172)

WARN gateio (Python 3 Async): (explain @ run-tests.js:191)

    /path/ccxt/python/ccxt/test/test_async.py:558: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
      asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    gateio using proxy ``
    EXCHANGE: gateio
    SYMBOL: BTC/USD
    CODE: ZRX
    gateio BTC/USD ticker None high: 65609.0 low: 64073.0 bid: 64958.24 ask: 64991.5 volume: 40525928.149905
    gateio fetched all 2176 tickers
    gateio fetched 10 OHLCVs
    gateio BTC/USD order book 2021-11-12T03:25:31.759Z bid: 64958.24 bidVolume: 0.3225 ask: 64991.5 askVolume: 0.3225
    gateio BTC/USD fetched 100 trades
    gateio BTC/USD fetch_orders() not supported
    gateio BTC/USD fetched 0 open orders
    gateio BTC/USD fetched 0 closed orders
    gateio ZRX fetch_transactions() not supported
    gateio fetched balance (explain @ run-tests.js:193)
WARN ["gateio"] (run-tests.js:272)
All done, 1 warnings (run-tests.js:276)
```

---

I've tried to update this line, to use `asyncio.run` instead, but then I just get an infinite loop and eventually the tests time out and fail

```
asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

**Timeout error**

```js
[100%] Testing gateio FAIL (testExchange @ run-tests.js:172)

FAILED gateio (Python 3 Async): (explain @ run-tests.js:190)

    timed out (explain @ run-tests.js:193)
FAIL ["gateio"] (run-tests.js:271)
All done, 1 failed (run-tests.js:276)
```

---

I'd like to know how to properly update this method so as to not get the deprecation warning and not get timed out

Answer (score 4):

The issue here lies in how the event loop is managed. `asyncio.run` always creates a brand new event loop internally. The API you're using seems like it uses `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in the `Exchange` class which creates a different event loop from the one `asyncio.run` creates and passes that one around. This causes problems, as the loop that the `Exchange` class created is just sitting there idle, so trying to run anything with that loop won't really run. To fix this, you need to ensure you're using the loop that `asyncio.run` creates, which means refactoring the code a bit and using `asyncio.get_running_loop()`. `asyncio.get_running_loop()` will return the currently running loop or throw an exception if one is not running, it will never create a new one.

To specifically fix the issue you have (bear in mind, this change may break other areas of the code)

Change the constructor of the `Exchange` class in `exchange.py` to use `asyncio.get_running_loop()` instead of `asyncio.get_event_loop()` like so:

```
class Exchange(BaseExchange):

    def __init__(self, config={}):
        if 'asyncio_loop' in config:
            self.asyncio_loop = config['asyncio_loop']
        self.asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() #this is the change here, note that this overwrites the loop from the config, so this could cause problems.
        self.aiohttp_trust_env = config.get('aiohttp_trust_env', self.aiohttp_trust_env)
        self.verify = config.get('verify', self.verify)
        self.own_session = 'session' not in config
        self.cafile = config.get('cafile', certifi.where())
        super(Exchange, self).__init__(config)
        self.throttle = None
        self.init_rest_rate_limiter()
        self.markets_loading = None
        self.reloading_markets = False
```

Next, you'll need to move your exchange init code into the `main` coroutine. This is so that when the constructor calls `get_running_loop` it will return the loop that `asyncio.run` created:

```
async def main():

  # instantiate all exchanges
  for id in ccxt.exchanges:
    if id == 'theocean':
      continue
    exchange = getattr(ccxt, id)
    exchange_config = {'verbose': argv.verbose}
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
      exchange_config.update({'enableRateLimit': True})
    if id in config:
      exchange_config = ccxt.Exchange.deep_extend(exchange_config, config[id])
    exchanges[id] = exchange(exchange_config)
    #other code as before...
```

This fix works, but bear in mind that the API itself may need to be refactored in a way that supports the way it handles the event loop to support the way `asyncio.run` creates and manages the event loop. In particular, the code in the `Exchange` class that can pull an event loop from a config may need to be refactored.

Comment: "In particular, the code in the Exchange class that can pull an event loop from a config may need to be refactored." - Yeah that part is a problem, I'm getting `<class 'RuntimeError'> no running event loop` because there is no running loop, how should it be refactored?